# Smoothing and manipulating x-axis

Tags: r, rstudio

I'm currently working on making a graph of the probability of exceedance of precipitation extremes. However, I'm struggling with the code.

This is what I've got so far:

```
PE2010 <- read.table(file="C:/Users/PE2001-2010.txt",header=TRUE)

plot(PE2010$Pre ~ PE2010$PE,
     col = "red",
     xlab = "Overschrijdingskans",
     ylab = "Neerslagintensiteit (mm/d)",
     main = "Overschrijdingskans voor de 3 simulaties")
```

The result is shown in the image:

[image: Result]

What i'd like to do:

1. Instead of a range 0 to 1 on the x-axis, I'd like it to go from 1 to 0
2. It would be nice if only values of 1, 0.1, 0.01 and 0.001 were shown on the x-axis
3. I'd like the data to be represented as a smooth curve, not as points as it is now. However, when using the "lines" function, a weird result shows up.

Summarized, I'd like the result to be something like this:

[image: Something]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without your actual data, it's hard to get it exactly right, but this is probably a good approximation of what you want:

```
# an index that will put the data in order from left to right
indx  <-  order(PE2010$PE)

plot(y =PE2010$Pre[indx],
     x = PE2010$PE[indx],
     col = "red",
     xlab = "Overschrijdingskans",
     ylab = "Neerslagintensiteit (mm/d)",
     main = "Overschrijdingskans voor de 3 simulaties",
     type = "l",
     # log transformt the x-axis
     log = 'x',
     # reverse the x axis
     xlim = range(PE2010$PE,na.rm=T)[2:1],
     # don't include the default axes
     axes=F
     )

# make the axes
box()
axis(2)
axis(1,at=c(1, 0.1, 0.01,0.001 ))
```